# Sorting a list of maps

Tags: java, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a list of maps

`List<Map<String, Object>> people = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();`

that gets populated like so

```
map.put("firstName",John);
map.put("lastName",Smith);
map.put("type","1"); //type is either 1 or a 0

people.add(map);
```

and what I want to do with this list after it gets populated is so have all the people as type `0` at the top of the list and all with type `1` at the bottom.

I know I need to use a `Comparator` but I have never used one before so I dont know how to use one or how it works.

Could someone help me out

Comment: Implement the `Comparator#compare()` method to check the value at key `type` on each map and return based on 1 or 0.

Comment: Why are you using Map to represent person info? Wouldn't it be simpler to create your own Person class and use list like this `List<Person>`?

Comment: @Pshemo yes but this is something for android to populate a list which needs a list of maps for that list adapter

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this

```
Collections.sort( people, new Comparator<Map<String, Object>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare( Map<String, Object> o1, Map<String, Object> o2 ) {
        return (Integer.parseInt((String)o1.get( "type" ))) - 
                (Integer.parseInt((String)o2.get( "type" )));
    }
} );
```

However, there are many ways to make this better.  If you cannot use a Person object to represent the map as suggested by @Pshemo, then at least, use a reasonable data type for your type attribute.  The best would be an enum:

```
public enum PersonType {
    TYPE_1, TYPE_2
}
```

Then the comparisons are much cleaner and faster and much more readable.

Comment: You need to add cast to String near `o1.get( "type" )` since type of result of `o1.get` is Object -> `Map<String, Object>`.

Comment: @Pshema, fixed, thanks for the correction.  Just goes to show what you can accomplish without a compiler :(...

Answer (score 2):

Comparator is just an interface that needs to be implemented, it contains only one method that needs to be overriden.

For example:

```
    List<Map<String, Object>> people = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();

    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map .put("firstName","John");
    map.put("lastName","Smith");
    map.put("type","1"); //type is either 1 or a 0

    people.add(map);

    Collections.sort(people, new Comparator<Map<String, Object>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Map<String, Object> o1, Map<String, Object> o2) {
            // you may compare your map here
            return 0;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 Collections.sort(people, new Comparator<Map<String, String>>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Map<String, String> m1, Map<String, String> m2) {
        return m1.get("type").compareTo(m2.get("type"));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this :

```
class ListByType 
{
    private static class MyComparator implements Comparator<HashMap<String,String>>
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(HashMap mp1 , HashMap mp2)
        {
            return ((String)(mp1.get("type")).compareTo((String)mp2.get("type"));
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        List<Map<String, String>> people = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
        HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        map.put("firstName","John");
        map.put("lastName","Smith");
        map.put("type","1"); //type is either 1 or a 0
        people.add(map);
        /*...
        ..
        ...
        Add more maps here..
        */
        //Sort the list
        Collections.sort(people,new MyComparator());
    }
}
```